# Compactness of the Fredholm Integral Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $D=[0,1]^d, d \in \Bbb N, k \in C(D \times D), (C(D), | | \cdot | |_{\infty})$ be a vector space and $$(T \varphi)(s) = \int_D k(s,t) \cdot \varphi(t) dt, \ \varphi \in C(D)$$ be an operator, which we already introduced in lecture as a bounded linear operator meaning $T \in L(C(D))$. I have to show that $T \in K(C(D))$ meaning it is a compact operator. My attempt to prove this: We know (using Heine Borel) that $D$ is compact. This means that we can make use of the fact that for subsets $A \subseteq C(D)$ we can use Arzelá-Ascoli to make out whether the set is totally bounded. Since $T \in L(C(D))$ we know that $\overline{T(B)}$ is bounded, so what we have to show is that $\overline{T(B)}$ is equicontinuous to get total boundedness (so it suffices to show equicontinuity of $T(B)$): Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall x,y \in D: |k(x,t) - k(y,t)| < \epsilon$. We then get: $$\sup_{\varphi \in T(B)} |\varphi(x) - \varphi(y)| = \sup_{\psi \in B} | \int_0^1 (k(x,t)-k(y,t))\psi(t)dt| \leq \sup_{\psi \in B} \int_0^1 |k(x,t) - k(y,t)| dt \cdot ||\psi||_{\infty} < \epsilon$$ since $\sup_{\psi \in B} ||\psi||_{\infty} = 1$. This should show equicontinuity of $T(B)$ and thus of $\overline{T(B)}$ if I didn't completely miss something. Can someone tell me whether this "proof scetch" up to now is correct?

Comment: This should be the right idea; however, it would be better to argue that Arzela-Ascoli gives total boundedness of $T(B)$, which in turn implies total boundedness of $\overline{T(B)}$ - since I am not sure if equicontinuity is also preserved by taking closures. By the way: I think I'm taking the same course as you do ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am pretty sure that closure preserves equicontinuity but ur argument certainly fits. Regarding the course: What a nice coincidence haha!

Comment: Another method is to show that if $k(s,t)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(s)g_i(t)$ then $T$ has finite rank.  For the general case use Stone-Weirstrass to approximate any continuous $k$ by a sequence of $k's$ as above.